# H264 video decode delay

Tags: android, h.264

Am working in H264 video rendering in Android application using FFMPEG library.I receive the video frame from RTSP protocol.While am playing the video in HD camera i got the delay in video decode.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Set [CODEC_FLAG_LOW_DELAY](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#ga153ac4631210154a5fbd364f5f6c3a37) in AVCodecContext->flags.